# R: Help reading a particular .mat file into R

Tags: r, matlab, mat-file, matlab-load

So I've been trying to read this particular .mat file into R. I don't know too much about matlab, but I know enough that the R.matlab package can only read uncompressed data into R, and to save it as uncompressed I need to save it as such in matlab by using 
`save new.mat -v6`.

Okay, so I did that, but when I used `readMat("new.mat")` in R, it just got stuck loading that forever. I also tried using package hdf5 via:

```
> hdf5load("new.mat", load=FALSE)->g
Error in hdf5load("new.mat", load = FALSE) : 
  can't handle hdf type 201331051
```

I'm not sure what this problem could be, but if anyone wants to try to figure this out the file is located at [http://dibernardo.tigem.it/MANTRA/MANTRA_online/Matlab_Code%26Data.html](http://dibernardo.tigem.it/MANTRA/MANTRA_online/Matlab_Code&Data.html)  and is called inventory.mat (the first file).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't know much about matlab either, but recently had some fun with it's open alternative called [octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/). If you do not need imports an a regular basis, `octave` might be a quick work around worth looking at.

Comment: R.matlab can read compressed data. I've found it necessary to reduce the size of the buffer for some large files when I already knew the correct ratio, but it is not provided by the interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular file has one object, `inventory`, which is a `struct` object, with a lot of different things inside of it.  Some are cell arrays, others are vectors of doubles or logicals, and a couple are matrices of doubles.  It looks like R.matlab does not like cells arrays within structs, but  I'm not sure what's causing issues for R to load this.  For reasons like this, I'd generally recommend avoiding mapping structs in Matlab to objects in R.  It is similar to a list, and this one can be transformed to a list, but it's not always a good idea.

I recommend creating a new file, one for each object, e.g. `ids = inventory.instance_ids` and save each object to either a separate .mat file, or save all of them, except for the inventory object, into 1 file.  Even better is to go to text, e.g via `csvwrite`, so that you can see what's being created.

I realize that's going around use of a Matlab to R reader, but having things in a common, universal format is much more useful for reproducibility than to acquire a bunch of different readers for a proprietary format.

Alternatively, you can pass objects in memory via `R.matlab`, or [this set of functions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5051) + the R/DCOM interface (on Windows).

Although this doesn't address how to use R.matlab, I've done a lot of transferring of data between R and Matlab, in both directions, and I find that it's best to avoid .mat files (and, similarly, .rdat files).  I like to pass objects in memory, so that I can inspect them on each side, or via standard text files.  Dealing with application specific file formats, especially those that change quite a bit and are inefficient (I'm looking at you MathWorks), is not a good use of time.  I appreciate the folks who work on readers, but having a lot more control over the data structures used in the target language is very much worth the space overhead of using a simple output file format.  In-memory data transfer is very nice because you can interface programs, but that may be a distraction if your only goal is to move data.

Comment: Agreed that writing to a text format is a good idea.  That way when problems occur you can inspect the contents of the file.  Passing `-ascii` to MATLAB's `save` function would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run the examples in http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/R.matlab.pdf on pages 22 to 24? That will test your ability to read from versions 4 and 5. I'm not sure that R cannot read compressed files. There is an Rcompresssion package in Omegahat.